# Customizing Ion-refresher and overflow effects

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I would like to change this ion-refresher behavior **(Ionic 3)**

[image: The current behavior]

The goal is to achieve this one below, in order to refresh the content without dragging the whole page down

[image: The goal]

I have done my research without any results, therefore I would like to know if it's possible to do it with **ion-refresher** or similar component.
**These are my Ionic informations:**

> **Ionic:**
>
> Ionic CLI          : 5.2.7
>     Ionic Framework    :
>   ionic-angular 3.9.2
>     @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3
>
> **Cordova:**
>
> Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
>     Cordova
>   Platforms : android 7.1.4, ios 4.5.5
>     Cordova Plugins   :
>   cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
>   3.1.2, (and 12 other plugins)
>
> **Utility:**
>
> cordova-res : not installed
>     native-run  : 0.2.8 (update
>   available: 0.2.9)